# Проблема с картинками при открытии HTML файла

Tags: html, css, изображения, img, background-image

При открытии файла HTML изображения не открываются, при запуске того же файла через Live-server, картинки подгружаются нормально. Проблема только с этими изображениями и только в этом участке кода

```
#slide1:checked ~ .controls label:nth-child(2),
#slide2:checked ~ .controls label:nth-child(3),
#slide3:checked ~ .controls label:nth-child(4),
#slide4:checked ~ .controls label:nth-child(1) {
  background-image: url(/img/control-red-second.png);
  float: right;
  margin: -50px 50px 0 0;
  display: block;
}
#slide1:checked ~ .controls label:nth-last-child(1),
#slide2:checked ~ .controls label:nth-last-child(4),
#slide3:checked ~ .controls label:nth-last-child(3),
#slide4:checked ~ .controls label:nth-last-child(2) {
  background-image: url(/img/control-red-first.png);
  float: left;
  margin: -50px 0px 0 300px;
  display: block;
}
```

В чем может быть проблема?

Answer (score 0):

Возможно при подключение картинки через `background-image: url(/img/control-red-second.png);`  надо прописать ширину и высоту ну или  `background-size`

Answer (score 0):

Нашел решение. Перед путем к картинке надо было добавить ..

```
  background-image: url(../img/control-red-first.png);
```